# Hide stack navigator header in drawer navigator screens

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

In my React Native app, there is a drawer navigator nested inside a stack navigator. I want to hide stack navigator header inside all drawer navigator screens, but visible in other screens.( Therefore, setting `headerMode: none` for all screens is not a solution )

[image]

This is what I tried, but is not working.

```js
DrawerNav: {
    screen: DrawerNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerMode:'none'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass **header: null** as **navigationOtpions** as shown below.

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
      {
        Home: {
          screen: YourScreen,

        },
      },
      {
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null,
        },
      },
    );
```